# What is the deepest accessible point on earth?

Tags: factoids, where-on-earth

There is [the Kola Superdeep Borehole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole) and [the Mariana trench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench) but both are not accessible to average humans.

What is the deepest point on earth I can reach?

Comment: If you are talking about the deepest ground where we can walk, then it is the [shore of the dead sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremes_on_Earth) (-400 meters).

Comment: Weird, I was sure we had this question, as I remember researching the Kola Borehole :/ Can't find it now.

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking for deepest place on the surface it would be the [Dead Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_sea) which is -427m deep.

If you're looking for the Ocean one there is a tourism organized by [Deep Ocean Expeditions](http://www.cnn.com/2012/03/19/travel/deep-sea-tourism/), which you can pay a pretty penny but explore like [James Cameron](http://deepseachallenge.com/) down to the depth of the Mariana Trench...

If you're looking for something more or less reasonable as far as prices are concerned take a look at [R.I.D.E.](http://www.stanleysubmarines.com/expeditions/2000ft-expedition/)

Comment: The Dead Sea shore is the *lowest* land surface but the word "deep" normally implies being under something. Are there (reasonably) accessible caves more than 427m below mean sea level?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krubera_Cave.  But it's explored depth is -2197m from the start but entry I think 2250m above the sea level.

Comment: There are mines that are accessible (tourism) that go pretty deep (kms), surely there must be one that gets deeper...

Comment: bah, apparently the [deepest open pit mine with respect to sea level is Tagebau Hambach in Germany, where the base of the pit is 293 meters below sea level](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120329053737AAt4bRF).

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_mine

Answer (score 10):

What you are probably looking for is this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_points_of_Earth#Elevation

Which tells us that, apart from the dead sea,

- lowest human-sized point underground is 3.9 kilometres (2.4 mi)[1] below ground at the TauTona Mine, Carletonville, South Africa

Google shows the entrance at about 1700m which would make the bottom 2.2km below ground you would have to go to sea to beat that as Karlson suggested.

Answer (score 9):

If you also mean the deepest point underground: The deepest natural cave is the Voronya/Krubera Cave in Abchasia near Georgia/Russia with an estimated depth of over 2000 meter (6500 ft). The entrance is in 2200 m height so you are still over water.

I have used this as background in a RPG game and searched photos for it. It contains very long shafts, an underground river...it is quite a fantastic cave.

Answer (score 8):

Deepest human accessible point in the world is the bottom of Kidd Mine in Timmins, Canada.  Kidd is 9,889 ft (3.014 km) deep and the city itself is only 100m above sea level.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidd_Mine

Comment: Nice addition, especially because the extremely deep diamond mines in South Africa are out of bounds. There is even a [report](http://blogs.agu.org/martianchronicles/2011/08/01/9800-feet/) of the visit available.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's the deepest, but the [LKAB Visitor Centre](http://www.kirunalapland.se/en/News/Guaranteed-departures-to-LKAB-InfoMine/) in  [Kiruna/Giron](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kiruna), Sweden, is easily accessible by daily buses, and is, if I recall correctly, 345 metre below the local surface.  Not nearly as deep as caves posted in other answers, but a lot more accessible for the average tourist.  The mining is currently 1385 metre below the surface, but is not open to regular visitors.